# Keep consecutive build numbers on different branches

Tags: fastlane

I'm using Fastlane and deploying beta versions to Crashlytics from different branches.
The problem is, I want to keep consecutive build numbers no matter what branch I ran Fastlane from.
I couldn't find a way to fetch the build number from another branch's plist file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eventually I managed to solve it by making the master branch my one source of truth. 
When running fastlane from a different branch (not the master), I switch to the master branch and increment the build number then go back to the branch and increment it as well.